# Find certain text, copy and paste into new sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code here that goes through my sheet column C and and find all the cells with "Geoff" in it and copies it and pastes it in "Geoff" sheet from active sheet. what I need it to accomplish is copying the whole row and pasting it into "Geoff" sheet.

```
Dim K As Long, r As Range, v As Variant
K = 1
Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
Set w1 = Sheets("Active")
Set w2 = Sheets("Geoff")
w1.Activate
For Each r In Intersect(Range("C:C"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    v = r.Value
    If InStr(v, "Geoff") > 0 Then
        r.Copy w2.Cells(K, 1)
        K = K + 1
    End If
Next r
```

it only copies Geoff from Column C I need it to copy the entire row. Any help or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
r.EntireRow.Copy w2.Cells(K, 1)
```

should work

Or if you want to be more selective:

```
r.EntireRow.Cells(1).Resize(1, numColsToCopy).Copy w2.Cells(K, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. Now I'm just trying to figure out how to make it paste at the first empty cell in column A. And make it delete what it copied from "Active" sheet after it pastes it into "Geoff" sheet.